# Multipla impressão com checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox

Tenho uma página onde listo os dados do banco, criei uma opção para que ele possa fazer a impressão de uma "carteira" com detalhes do registro porém apenas para a linha selecionada. O problema é que só imprime um por vez desperdiçando papel.

Preciso criar uma opção para que o usuário possa imprimir mais de um registro usando o checkbox.

**Página que lista dos dados:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resultado esperado apos selecionar quatros registros:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código que lista os dados do banco**

```html
<?php $cpf_visitado=$ _SESSION[ 'usuarioCpf']; $result_solicitacao="
 SELECT tb_movto_visitas.*, tb_cad_visitantes.nom_visitante, tb_cad_motivos.des_motivo, usuarios.nome  FROM tb_movto_visitas
 LEFT JOIN tb_cad_visitantes ON tb_movto_visitas.tb_cad_visitantes_cod_visitante = tb_cad_visitantes.cpf AND tb_movto_visitas.cod_visitado = tb_cad_visitantes.cpf_visitado
 LEFT JOIN tb_cad_motivos ON tb_movto_visitas.tb_cad_motivos_cod_motivo = tb_cad_motivos.cod_motivo
 LEFT JOIN usuarios ON tb_movto_visitas.cod_visitado = usuarios.id

 WHERE  tb_movto_visitas.`cod_visitado` = $cpf_visitado ORDER BY tb_movto_visitas.`sol_visita` DESC " ; $resultado_solicitacao=m ysqli_query($conn, $result_solicitacao); include_once( "adm/../functions.php"); ?>


<div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Solicitações</h1>
  </div>

  <form name="cad_usuario" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="imprime_carteira_lote.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">


        <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="pull-right">
                <a href="colaborador.php?link=22">
                  <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-success'>Cadastrar</button>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br>

            <div class="row">
              <div id="lista_sol2">
                <table id="lista_sol" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <thead>

                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Visitante</th>
                    <th>Responsável</th>
                    <th>Chegada</th>
                    <th>Saída</th>
                    <th>Situação</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Ação</th>
                    <th class="text-center">#</th>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <?php while ($row_solicitacao=m ysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_solicitacao)) { ?>
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text-center">
                        <?php echo $row_solicitacao[ "sol_visita"]; ?>
                      </td>



                      <td>
                        <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ "nom_visitante"]); ?>
                      </td>


                      <td>
                        <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ "nom_solicitante"]); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php echo date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime($row_solicitacao[ "dat_chegada"])); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <?php echo date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime($row_solicitacao[ "dat_prev_saida"])); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td class="text-left">
                        <?php $status=$ row_solicitacao[ 'aprovado']; switch ($status) { case "": echo "Pendente"; break; case "A": echo "Aprovada"; break; case "R": echo "Rejeitada"; break; case "F": echo "Fechada"; break; } ?>
                      </td>
                      <td class="text-center">

                        <a href="colaborador.php?link=19&id=<?php echo $row_solicitacao[" sol_visita "]; ?>">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">Visualizar</button>
                        </a>
                        <?php if ($row_solicitacao[ "aprovado"]=="" && $row_solicitacao[ "dat_prorroga_1"]==n ull) : ?>
                        <a href="colaborador.php?link=21&id=<?php echo $row_solicitacao[" sol_visita "]; ?>&v1=<?php echo $row_solicitacao["tb_cad_visitantes_cod_visitante "]; ?>">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">Editar</button>
                        </a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger bootbox-delete" item-data="<?php echo $row_solicitacao[" sol_visita "]; ?>" id="apagar" name="apagar">Apagar</button>

                        <?php else : ?>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning hasTooltip" title="Possui movimentos" disabled="disabled">Editar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger  hasTooltip" title="Possui movimentos" disabled="disabled">Apagar</button>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php if ($row_solicitacao[ "aprovado"]=="A" && $row_solicitacao[ "dat_baixa"]==n ull) : ?>

                        <a href="colaborador.php?link=8&id=<?php echo $row_solicitacao[" sol_visita "]; ?>&v1=<?php echo $row_solicitacao["tb_cad_visitantes_cod_visitante "]; ?>">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">Imprimir</button>
                        </a>


                        <?php endif; ?>

                      </td>


                      <td class="text-center">



                        <label class="form-checkbox form-normal form-primary form-text">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="imp_lote" name="imp_lote">
                        </label>


                      </td>


                    </tr>


                    <?php } ?>

                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="imprimir Selecionados" onclick="return val_cad_nivel_acesso()">
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

**Código que gera a carteira:**

```html
<?php $id=$ _GET[ 'id']; //Buscar os dados referente ao usuario situado neste id $result_solicitacao="
 SELECT tb_movto_visitas.*, tb_cad_visitantes.nom_visitante, tb_cad_visitantes.rg, tb_cad_visitantes.cpf, tb_cad_motivos.des_motivo, usuarios.nome  FROM tb_movto_visitas
 LEFT JOIN tb_cad_visitantes ON tb_movto_visitas.tb_cad_visitantes_cod_visitante = tb_cad_visitantes.cpf AND tb_movto_visitas.cod_visitado = tb_cad_visitantes.cpf_visitado
 LEFT JOIN tb_cad_motivos ON tb_movto_visitas.tb_cad_motivos_cod_motivo = tb_cad_motivos.cod_motivo
 LEFT JOIN usuarios ON tb_movto_visitas.cod_visitado = usuarios.cpf2
 WHERE sol_visita = '$id' LIMIT 1" ; $resultado_solicitacao=m ysqli_query($conn, $result_solicitacao); $row_solicitacao=m ysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_solicitacao); ?>


<style type="text/css">
  .titulo1 {
    text-align: center
  }
  .div {
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  .div2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .div3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #808080;
  }
  .div4 {
    font-size: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
  .div5 {
    font-size: 7px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>



<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row container-fluid">

        <table border="0" class="div4">
          <thead>

          </thead>
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td rowspan="14" class="div5"> <font color="Black"> 
                                &nbsp; 1 - Este documento é a sua autorização antê-lo sempre em seu<br>&nbsp; poder.  <br>
                                &nbsp; 2 - É obrigação do VISITADO informar a Administração Patrimonial <BR>&nbsp;qualquer alteração no presente documento (dado de permanência,&nbsp;<BR>&nbsp; mudança de residência, etc...)<br>
                               .

                                </font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" align="lefth" class="div2">&nbsp;
                <img src="imagens/logo.png" class="div"> <font color="Black" align="center"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Segurança</b></font>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" align="center"> <font color="Black"><b>Autorização de Visita Nº: <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao['sol_visita']); ?></b></font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" align="center" class="div3"><font color="Black">&nbsp;<b>DADOS DO VISITANTE</b></font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">&nbsp;<b>Nome: <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao['nom_visitante']); ?></b>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;RG:
                <?php echo $row_solicitacao[ 'rg']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;CPF:
                <?php echo $row_solicitacao[ 'cpf']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;Cidade:
                <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ 'cidade']); ?>
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;Transp:
                <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ 'tip_transporte']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;Chegada:
                <?php echo date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime($row_solicitacao[ 'dat_chegada'])); ?>
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;Saída:
                <?php echo date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime($row_solicitacao[ 'dat_prev_saida'])); ?>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" align="center" class="div3"><font color="Black"><b>DADOS DO VISITADO</b></font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" style="white-space: initial">&nbsp;Nome:
                <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ 'nome']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">&nbsp;Endereço:
                <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ 'end_visitado']); ?>-
                <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ 'end_bairro']); ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;Matricula :</td>
              <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <font color="ffffff ">.</font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">&nbsp;.</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">&nbsp;Emitido por:
                <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ 'cod_aprovador_1']); ?>
              </td>
            </tr>


          </tbody>
        </table>


      </div>

    </div>
    <div text-right noprint ">
                    <button id="btn " class="btn btn-success " onclick="window.print(); ">Imprimir</button>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: você poderia passar esse código ?

Comment: Posso sim, me manda um e-mail que te envio os arquivos  dgopereira@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Primeira coisa altera o seu checkbox dessa forma:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="imp_lote" name="imp_lote[]" value="<?php echo $row_solicitacao[" sol_visita "]; ?>">
```

**Código que gera a carteira EM LOTE:**

```html
<?php 
$ids = implode(',',$_POST['imp_lote']); // CONCATENA OS VALUES DOS CHECKBOX MARCADOS
$result_solicitacao="
 SELECT tb_movto_visitas.*, tb_cad_visitantes.nom_visitante, tb_cad_visitantes.rg, tb_cad_visitantes.cpf, tb_cad_motivos.des_motivo, usuarios.nome  FROM tb_movto_visitas
 LEFT JOIN tb_cad_visitantes ON tb_movto_visitas.tb_cad_visitantes_cod_visitante = tb_cad_visitantes.cpf AND tb_movto_visitas.cod_visitado = tb_cad_visitantes.cpf_visitado
 LEFT JOIN tb_cad_motivos ON tb_movto_visitas.tb_cad_motivos_cod_motivo = tb_cad_motivos.cod_motivo
 LEFT JOIN usuarios ON tb_movto_visitas.cod_visitado = usuarios.cpf2
 WHERE sol_visita IN($id)" ; 
 $resultado_solicitacao=mysqli_query($conn, $result_solicitacao); 
  ?>


<style type="text/css">
  .titulo1 {
    text-align: center
  }
  .div {
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  .div2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .div3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #808080;
  }
  .div4 {
    font-size: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    table-layout: fixed;
  }
  .div5 {
    font-size: 7px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
</style>

<?php
while($row_solicitacao = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_solicitacao)){
?>

<div class="col-sm-12">
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row container-fluid">

        <table border="0" class="div4">
          <thead>

          </thead>
          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td rowspan="14" class="div5"> <font color="Black"> 
                                &nbsp; 1 - Este documento é a sua autorização antê-lo sempre em seu<br>&nbsp; poder.  <br>
                                &nbsp; 2 - É obrigação do VISITADO informar a Administração Patrimonial <BR>&nbsp;qualquer alteração no presente documento (dado de permanência,&nbsp;<BR>&nbsp; mudança de residência, etc...)<br>
                               .

                                </font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" align="lefth" class="div2">&nbsp;
                <img src="imagens/logo.png" class="div"> <font color="Black" align="center"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Segurança</b></font>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" align="center"> <font color="Black"><b>Autorização de Visita Nº: <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao['sol_visita']); ?></b></font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" align="center" class="div3"><font color="Black">&nbsp;<b>DADOS DO VISITANTE</b></font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">&nbsp;<b>Nome: <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao['nom_visitante']); ?></b>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;RG:
                <?php echo $row_solicitacao[ 'rg']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;CPF:
                <?php echo $row_solicitacao[ 'cpf']; ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;Cidade:
                <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ 'cidade']); ?>
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;Transp:
                <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ 'tip_transporte']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;Chegada:
                <?php echo date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime($row_solicitacao[ 'dat_chegada'])); ?>
              </td>
              <td>&nbsp;Saída:
                <?php echo date( 'd/m/Y', strtotime($row_solicitacao[ 'dat_prev_saida'])); ?>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" align="center" class="div3"><font color="Black"><b>DADOS DO VISITADO</b></font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3" style="white-space: initial">&nbsp;Nome:
                <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ 'nome']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">&nbsp;Endereço:
                <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ 'end_visitado']); ?>-
                <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ 'end_bairro']); ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">&nbsp;Matricula :</td>
              <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <font color="ffffff ">.</font>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">&nbsp;.</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">&nbsp;Emitido por:
                <?php echo utf8_encode($row_solicitacao[ 'cod_aprovador_1']); ?>
              </td>
            </tr>


          </tbody>
        </table>


      </div>

    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>    
    <div text-right noprint ">
                    <button id="btn " class="btn btn-success " onclick="window.print(); ">Imprimir</button>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Olá meu amigo! Muito obrigado! Simplesmente funcionou perfeitamente! impressionante!!! Ficou ótimo!! Muito obrigado mesmo!

Comment: De nada Diego, elege a resposta então :D